# Computer not wake up sometime after standby

Tags: boot, motherboard, hardware-failure, wake-up

I have a crazy problem with my new pc.

The computer worked fine until power on but the problem is that when I put my computer to sleep (or sometime shutdown) after several minutes computer dies and I can't turn on again:

No cpu fan, no power fan not power light. I just can see motherboard green light on.

After several times disconnecting the cables and connecting them again the computer come back on.

I thought the problem related to the power supply and I changed that but the problem is not solved!

**Hardware:**

```
       ASUS - H81-PLUS
       Crucial SSD BX100 120GB
       ASUS - GeForce GT 730 - 2GB 
       GREEN - GP430A-EU+
       Intel Core i5 - 3.2GHz - 4460
       Corsair - XMS3 8GB - 1600
```

Comment: What operating system (including OS version) is it running?

Comment: Windows 10 64Bit Enterprise @CBHacking

Comment: Does your area suffer from power distribution issues such as brownouts?

Comment: @Burgi no, i connect other device like loptop , mobile and ... without any problem